# How do I make the mathematical constant e (as in exp(1)) in a textView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like the textView to show the mathematical constant e. I tried using an italic "e", but that looks different. I looked for an HTML code to represent it, but couldn't find one. So how do I type e into a textView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML), there is no HTML code for *e*.  In addition, viewing the source of [Wikipedia's Page on *e*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) shows that they simply make it slightly larger, italic, **and `font-family:serif`**.  There's no need for anything else really - its just a recognized constant but still the English letter. If it was actually a latin character you may want to find one, but in this case a simple "*e*" seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to examine this link: http://www.codetable.net/unicodecharacters?page=1.
Well using just "e" is fine actually.